# Devcot + Postfix + Mail client issue + Virtual Min

Tags: postfix-mta, centos7, thunderbird

First of all i need to say sorry for my bad english.

I am having a issue with devecot + Postfix

i install centos 7 with virtual min . i can easily access all my emails from roundcube. but when i try to connect it with outlook or thunderbird it gives me error saying

mail client says : Thunder bird is failed to find the setting of this account

Than i check my maillog errors are something like this

```
Feb 16 18:41:27 bluehorntech postfix/smtpd[29217]: connect from unknown[86.188.129.1]
Feb 16 18:41:27 bluehorntech postfix/smtpd[29217]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[86.188.129.1]

Feb 16 18:41:27 bluehorntech postfix/smtpd[29217]: disconnect from unknown[86.188.129.1]
```

i have check my main.cf all fine.

if i try to not to give mail.domainname just give what i find in resolver it give me auth error.

Can any one help me on this why its doing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If roundcube able to access dovecot without problem, maybe firewall issue. Please provide iptables-save result, and make sure dovecot listen to WAN interface.

Comment: yes its fixed wan issue. its not properly communicating with server